# Regex replace conditional character

Tags: java, python, regex

I need to remove any 'h' in a string if it comes after a vowel.

```
E.g.
    John -> Jon
    Baht -> Bat
    Hot -> Hot (no change)
    Rhythm -> Rhythm (no change)
```

Finding the words isnt a problem, but removing the 'h' is as I still need the original vowel. Can this be done in one regex?

Answer (score 2):

The regex for matching `h` after a vowel would be a positive lookbehind one

```
(?<=a|e|y|u|o|a)h
```

And you can do

```
re.sub(r"([a-zA-Z]*?)(?<=a|e|y|u|o|a)h([a-zA-Z]*)",r"\1\2",s)
```

However, if you can have more than one `h` after a vowel in a string, you would need to do several iterations, since regex doesn't support dynamic matching groups

```
import re

s = "bahtbaht"
s1 = s

while True:
    s1 = re.sub(r"([a-zA-Z]*?)(?<=a|e|y|u|o|a)h([a-zA-Z]*)",r"\1\2",s)
    if len(s1) == len(s):
        break
    s = s1

print(s1)
```

In a more proper form, using function for `repl`

```
import re

def subit(m):
    match, = m.groups()
    return match

s = "bahtbaht"

print(re.sub(r"([a-zA-Z]*?)(?:(?<=a|e|y|u|o|a)h|$)",subit,s))
```

A much simplier answer, thanks to @tobias_k

```
re.sub(r"([aeiou])h", r"\1", s, flags = re.I)
```

Comment: What's wrong with `re.sub(r"([aeiou])h", r"\1", s)`? Seems to work just fine, too. Also, might add `re.I` flag.

Comment: @tobias_k nothing wrong, will edit the answer, thanks!